# Limiting Domain Admins permissions on a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a SQL Server 2012 machine and I want to limit the Domain Admins permissions. What can I do to make sure that the Domain Admins have read only permissions for the databases and nothing else for SQL Server?

I am interested in limiting their permissions for the SQL Server install. They can do whatever they want on the Windows Server 2008 OS.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

By default domain admins don't have access to a SQL 2012 instance, because by default `builtin\administrator` (which are the local admins on the machine) are not a login in SQL Server itself.

The default has changed [starting 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280562%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> By default, the local Windows Group BUILTIN\Administrator is no longer
>   included in the SQL Server sysadmin fixed server role on new SQL
>   Server 2008 installations.

So unless someone added them in SQL Server the local admins/domain admins shouldn't have permissions on the instance.

That doesn't mean they can't give themselves permissions, as some case of emergency solution they can [start sql in single user mode and connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx) but that requires a server restart.

On the other hand, on 2008 R2 this trick would still work: [Think Your Windows Administrators Don’t Have Access to SQL Server 2008 by Default? Think Again](https://www.0xsql.com/2011/07/10/think-your-windows-administrators-dont-have-access-to-sql-server-2008-by-default-think-again/)